# Prove that the diagonals of a trapezoid, one of whose bases is twice as long as the other, divide its midsegment into three equal parts.

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I am not sure where to start. A hint would be great to start off this problem.

Comment: A diagram is key. Start there. Then look for similar triangles.

Comment: Can you use the theorem that, in any triangle $ABC$, the line segment joining the midpoints of $AB$ and $AC$ is half as long as $BC$? If so, it can simplify your work here. If not, then I think you should try to prove that triangle theorem yourself (using similar triangles, as @quasi suggests).

Comment: Extend the legs of the trapezoid to form a triangle.